# F1 Results with Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

What is the most simple solution to do this ?

Define a function for calculating the series of Formula 1 race in function "f1Results". The parameter is a list whose elements are lists based on the result of each Grand Prix. Each such list shall contain the names of the competitors listed by the GP result (the winner is the first of the list). The result of the function has to be a list of names of F1 pilots sorted by number of points in the overall F1 season.

```
   f1Results :: [[String]] -> [String]
```

Points have to be granted for each position like in the list bellow (again the 25 is for the winner) pointsScoring (eg: 1st place 25 points, 2nd place 18 points, etc.).

```
   pointsScoring :: [Int]
   pointsScoring = [25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: map zip, concat, groupBy, map sum, orderBy, map fst...

Comment: -3 rly ??? for what ?

Comment: While I did not downvote this question, I suspect downvoters reacted to the fact that you did not show any attempt to solve the problem. Bluntly put, to some voters might look as a "please do my homework for me" question. It usually helps to state where the question is coming from (exercise from a book? website? homework?), to show some attempt of yours (even some informal ideas, not necessarily some Haskell code), and to state the point(s) on which you need help.

Comment: No homework, only as a task for myself to learn it. :) yah... I get it.. but people see im new here.. then why devote me if i dont even know how to post things.. now i will know cause u  told me.. but its a bit rude from them :/

Comment: Sure I could show some attempts, i just deleted them cause they werent even enough to compile. Im new to that as I said. Guess i chose a hard one for start. But logicaly seemed to be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a constant for what the scoring is

```
scoring :: [Int]
scoring = [25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1]
```

Then you need a way for pairing up a driver with the score they got.  Whenever you're pairing two things in Haskell, the canonical choice is to use a tuple.  The easiest way to construct a list of tuples from two lists is the `zip` function:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

And in this case can be used to assign scores for a race:

```
assignScores :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
assignScores race = zip race scoring
```

Now, we need a way to total up the scores for a driver for each race.  We want to be able to turn something like

```
[("Bob", 12), ("Joe", 10), ("Bob", 18), ("Joe", 25)]
```

into

```
[("Bob", 30), ("Joe", 35)]
```

The easiest way would be to make a single list of all the scores for all the races

```
assignAllScores :: [[String]] -> [(String, Int)]
assignAllScores races = concatMap assignScores races
```

Then we can use `sortBy` from `Data.List` to get all the same names next to each other

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
compare :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering

sortByDriver :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sortByDriver races = sortBy (\(n1, s1) (n2, s2) -> compare n1 n2) races
```

Then we can use `groupBy` (also from `Data.List`) to group them all by name

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]

groupByDriver :: [(String, Int)] -> [[(String, Int)]]
groupByDriver races = groupBy (\(n1, s1) (n2, s2) -> n1 == n2) races
```

But this gives us a list like

```
[[("Bob", 12), ("Bob", 18)], [("Joe", 10), ("Joe", 25)]]
```

We now need a way to convert this into the form

```
[("Bob", [12, 18]), ("Joe", [10, 25])]
```

where all the scores are aggregated back into a list, and we don't repeat the names at all.  This is left as an exercise.

```
aggregateScores :: [[(String, Int)]] -> [(String, [Int])]
```

Then we can finally calculate the sum of these scores

```
sumScores :: [(String, [Int])] -> [(String, Int)]
sumScores races = map (\(name, scores) -> (name, sum scores)) races
```

Then finally we can sort by the scores to get everyone in order

```
sortByScore :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sortByScore races = sortBy (\(n1, s1) (n2, s2) -> compare s2 s1) races
```

Notice that I have `compare s2 s1` instead of `compare s1 s2`, this means it will be sorted in descending order instead of ascending order.

The last step is to strip out the scores, now we have our list of drivers in order from winner to loser

```
removeScores :: [(String, Int)] -> [String]
removeScores races = map fst races
```

So to combine everything together into one function

```
f1Results :: [[String]] -> [String]
f1Results races =
    removeScores $
    sortByScore  $
    sumScores    $
    aggregateScores $
    groupByDriver $
    sortByDriver $
    assignAllScores races
```

---

There are several tricks that can make this code shorter, namely `Data.Function.on`, `Data.Ord.comparing`, and a fun operator from `Control.Arrow`.  Don't turn this in as homework, I just wanted to show an alternative that uses less code.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

scoring :: [Int]
scoring = [25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1]

f1Results :: [[String]] -> [String]
f1Results =
    map fst . sortBy (on (flip compare) snd) .
    map ((head *** sum) . unzip) .
    groupBy (on (==) fst) . sortBy (comparing fst) .
    concatMap (`zip` scoring)
```

Or using `Data.Map`:

```
import Data.Map (assocs, fromListWith)
import Data.List
import Data.Ord (comparing)

scoring :: [Int]
scoring = [25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1]

f1Results :: [[String]] -> [String]
f1Results =
    reverse . map fst . sortBy (comparing snd) .
    assocs . fromListWith (+) .
    concatMap (`zip` scoring)
```

Comment: I can follow your code.. it's delicate man! But couldn't figure out how to make the aggregateScores  always some errors show up.. and it also says:  " Missing binding for variable "zip" in type signature " when i try to compile it :/   ... And those shortened versions at the end are pretty cool! .. Hope i'll know this language one day as you... :) Just please help me finish this. I took this for myself as a chalenge but I failed.

Comment: Plus: Something is missing here. Where did you created a list of races ? It would be great if i have a list like this: `[Vettel,Ricciardo,Rosberg,Hamilton,Raikonen,Alonso,Massa,Perez,Magnusen,Button]` and from this list, i could create as many as i want with different positions... Ah man so hard :(

Comment: @MarkedOne 1) you don't need to include the type signatures that don't have definitions.  I guess I should have been more clear above, I only put those there as reference for what their type signatures are.  Just make sure you have the right libraries imported and they'll be in scope.  2) I just typed up something quickly with three racers `Bob`, `Joe`, and `Steve`, but if you want to generate a bunch of example data off of a list of driver names, check out the `permutations` function in `Data.List`, you can use it generate every possible permutation, then take the first 10 or so as input.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to fromListWith and infix as flip.

Comment: Why does it always says:  "  Missing binding for variable "sortBy" in type signature " .. also for other definitions :/

Comment: " bheklir " could you please give me a contact on you ?  FB/skype/email ??? I would appriciate that :/ .. Please.

Comment: @MarkedOne you can email me at bheklilr2 at gmail.

Comment: thanks.. i already solved it yesterday :) .. but thanks so much, for everything

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use a map where the keys are the drivers' names and the values are the scores. To associate scores with drivers for each sublist in f1results, one could zip the sublist with pointsScoring. A function could take each of the zipped sublists and add the score for each driver encountered in (or newly added to) the map. Then sort the map according to the values.

For example,

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List(sortBy)

pointsScoring :: [Int] 
pointsScoring = [25, 18, 15, 12]

f1List :: [[String]]
f1List = [["alex","bart","cecyl","dark"]
         ,["dark","bart","cecyl","alex"]
         ,["bart","cecyl","alex","dark"]]

f1Results :: [[String]] -> [String]
f1Results list = map fst . sortBy (\(n1,s1) (n2,s2) -> compare s2 s1) . M.toList 
               $ foldr f M.empty (concatMap (zip pointsScoring) list)
  where f (score,name) results = M.insertWithKey updateMap name score results
        updateMap key newValue oldValue = newValue + oldValue
```

Output:

```
*Main> f1Results f1List
["bart","alex","dark","cecyl"]
```