# Filter by fst and count by snd of pair

Tags: haskell

I want to define function pointCounts which takes a list of pairs in which first member is name and second the point value and return list of pairs with counted point for each name.

I struggle with this for days, but I can't figure how to do this.

The input example should look like:

`pointCount  [("Ferp",25),("Herp",18),("Derp",15),("Ferp",25),("Herp",15),("Derp",18),("Jon",10)]`

And the desired output example:

```
[("Ferp",50),("Herp",33),("Derp",33),("Jon",10)]
```

Comment: [I helped someone with a similar problem the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580319/f1-results-with-haskell/22580945#22580945).  I wouldn't consider this a duplicate question, but the same problem is being solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution using nothing more exotic than lists.  But cdk's solution is simpler and has better running time.

```
import Data.List

pointCount :: Num a => [(String, a)] -> [(String, a)]
pointCount [] = []
pointCount ((x, n):xs) =
    let (eqx, neqx) = partition ((==x).fst) xs in
        (x, n + (sum$ map snd eqx)) : pointCount neqx
```

Answer (score 6):

I used `Data.Map` as an intermediate data structure:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

pointCount :: Num a => [(String, a)] -> [(String, a)]
pointCount = M.toList . foldr f M.empty
    where f (name, val) = M.insertWith (+) name val
          -- or pointfree
          -- f = uncurry (M.insertWith (+))
```

or even better (as Daniel Wagner points out)

```
pointCount = M.toList . M.fromListWith (+)
```

Comment: If the names can be long, it might pay to hash them or use a trie or something.

Comment: @dfeuer (or rather, people who don't know what "or something" might be).  `Data.HashMap` exists and is useful for such cases.  Two implementations exist, see the `hashmap` and `unordered-containers` packages.

Comment: I'll add the `critbit` package to the list, it's designed to efficiently index `ByteString`/`Text` keys. The performance is about the same as a hash map, but it provides some convenience functions that hash maps cannot (none of which are required for this answer, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, assuming that the order of the result doesn't matter and it's only used on small lists (i.e., efficiency doesn't really matter):

```
import           Data.Ord      (comparing)
import           Data.Function (on)
import           Data.List     (groupBy, sortBy, foldl1')

pointCount :: Num a => [(String, a)] -> [(String, a)]
pointCount =   map     (foldl1' sumSecond)
             . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
             . sortBy  (comparing fst)
  where
    sumSecond :: Num a => (String, a) -> (String, a) -> (String, a)
    sumSecond (_, accum) (name, v) = (name, accum + v)
```

Here's another possible (similar) solution that takes advantage of the semigroup nature of summation, finding the first item of a non-empty list and of pairs of semigroups, as well as the fact that you get a semigroup when you compose two semigroups (using the `semigroups` and `semigroupoids` packages):

```
import           Data.Ord                  (comparing)
import           Data.Function             (on)
import           Data.List                 (groupBy, sortBy)
import           Data.Semigroup            (First (..), Sum (..))
import           Data.Semigroup.Foldable   (foldMap1)
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE
import           Control.Arrow             ((***))

pointCount :: Num a => [(String, a)] -> [(String, a)]
pointCount =   map     ( unpackResult
                       . foldMap1 packSemigroup
                       . NE.fromList
                       )
             . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
             . sortBy  (comparing fst)
  where
    packSemigroup :: Num a => (String, a) -> (First String, Sum a)
    packSemigroup   = First *** Sum

    unpackResult  :: Num a => (First String, Sum a) -> (String, a)
    unpackResult = getFirst *** getSum
```

I'd probably go with the first solution, but the second one illustrates how the essence of the problem can be viewed as an operation on a composition of semigroups. The operation is specifically a semigroup homomorphism, represented by the `unpackResult . foldMap1 packSemigroup` part.